# How to run selenium webdriver code once element is present

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Everything I've seen over the past month of looking is outdated.
Here's my problem, I traverse through about 5 different pages on one website before I get to the data I need. I can't fire off a `driver.get` as the url stays the same for all 5 different pages.

Since `Node.js` is asynchronous it runs the code before the element is present. I realize I could use a timeout, but i'm running this code 100's of times so a timeout won't work.

Everyone online says to do this, but it's outdated and doesn't work:

```
driver.findElement(By.css('#gridsortlink')).then(function(webElement) {
webElement.isElementPresent(By.css('#gridsortlink'))
.then(function(found) { console.log(found); });
});
```

If you do know how to do this that'd be great as I've been looking for a month now for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tried attempt looks incorrect, you should try as below :-

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#gridsortlink')), 5 * 1000).then(function(found) {
    console.log(found);
});
```

Comment: +Saurabh Gaur I tried that and it gave me the error until.elementLocated     is not a function

Comment: @GabeD. Sorry, there was some mistakes, try with updated code and let me know

Comment: Thanks @SaurabhGaur that fixed my Problem

Answer (score 0):

In place of webElement.isElementPresent try to use driver.isElementPresent

```
driver.findElement(By.css('#gridsortlink')).then(function(webElement) {
driver.isElementPresent(By.css('#gridsortlink'))
.then(function(found) { console.log(found); });
});
```

I don't have access to your application thats why I created a demo code for gmail where I am putting some wrong value in Email field and after some time I am getting an error message. and the output here is 'true'.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
var By = webdriver.By;
driver.get('http://gmail.com');

driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).then(function(emailText){
   emailText.sendKeys("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddddddd").then(function(){
     driver.findElement(By.id("next")).then(function(submit){
        submit.click().then(function(){
             driver.isElementPresent(By.className("error-msg")).then(function(text){
                console.log(text);
             });
        });
     });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java code:**

```
if((driver.findElements(By.css('#gridsortlink')).size())==1)    
{
system.out.println(executecode);
}
else
{
system.out.println(element is not exist in webpage);
}
```

You can check element is present or not.

`driver.findElements(By.css('#gridsortlink')).size()` this row returns to **0 or 1**.

1 means - Element exists on webpage.

0 means - Element does not exist on webpage.

Try in your code.